# Create stock picking from another model - Odoo v9 community

Tags: python, odoo

I have inherited `stock.picking`, so I need to create a picking from `fleet.vehicle.log.services`

So far, I'm thinking about adding this to a button, which will contain a `create()` function, such as:

```
@api.model
def create(self,vals):
    vals = {'location_id': '', 'location_dest_id':'', 'product_id':'', 'product_qty':''}
    res = super(stock.picking, self).create(vals)
    return res
```

But, my problem is that I don't know if this is the correct way to do it.

For example, `location_id` should be the location added to the form, take this location and create the `stock.picking` same with other fields.

I hope I'm explaining myself, I'm new to the Odoo v9 API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you re-assign value for vals, all the existing data will be replaced. It's better to update vals and then call super()

```
vals['location_id'] = ''
# vals['location_dest_id'] = .. and so on
#.. then call super
```